# How to compare a word in a sentence in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have database which contain a table(quotes_final). There is column which contains many quotes. now i want to make tags like happy,sad, popular, great etc. now i want to search these tags in quotes.

```
I am running these query but it i giving only few result and not all
SELECT name,quotes FROM `author_final`,`quotes_final` WHERE `author_final`.id = `quotes_final`.authorId and `quotes_final`.quotes like 'Age%'
```

This is giving me the quotes only Starting with Age and not the quotes which contains age in the middle or anywhere else in the sentence. 
What should I do to get all the result.

Note:- if I use %Age% - This is giving wrong result like it also fetch the quotes with words like message, massage, marriage etc.

Comment: `quotes like '% Age %'` or `quotes like '% Age.%'`

Comment: brother you haven't read my note. I have already tried this but this doesn't give the accurate result.

Comment: Nope. You haven't tried that. Have a look again.

Comment: quotes like '%age%' and quotes not in ('message,'massage','marriage')

Comment: give a sample of your column value

Comment: yes buddy I got your point thanks it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE INSTR('mycol', 'abc') > 0
```

The above example return all rows in table “mytable” where the column “mycol” contains the string “abc”.

Comment: You can use select * from mytable where mycol like "%abc%"; for check it contains it or not .